# Turning (,,,text,,4,text,3,,) into (text,4,text,3) using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone suggest a regEx to change `(,,,text,,4,text,3,,)` to `(text,4,text,3)` with javascript String.replace() method?

Comment: This might be very difficult due to the randomness of the commas...

Comment: You don't really need regexes for things like this. Just 1/ Recursively replace all double commas with single ones and 2/ Replace `(,` with `(` and `,)` with `)`

Comment: Well that's what i thought, my solution is just remove the parenthesis, perform `String.split(,)` and remove the empty cells from the returned array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex based solution that does it in a single `replace` call:

```
var re = /,+(?=,)|,+(?=\))|(\(),+/g; 

var result = input.replace(re, '$1');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pH4pO0/1)

Comment: Its leaving some spaces there but not something that we can't handle :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to make without regular expressions, it's better if you make an array without empty items:

```js
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

var arr = ",,,text,,4,text,3,,".split(","); //convert string into array
arr.clean(""); // clean all empty items

console.log(arr); // returns ["text","4","text","3"]
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos, that's pretty much what i had in mind, just wanted be sure as i really like doing stuff with regEx :)

Comment: Ok, I can recommend you this page https://regex101.com/#javascript to test and improve with explanations your regular expressions, it's a good way to understand and learn to use it

Comment: Mixing in a function to the prototype makes it a bit harder to mantain. Simply `",,,text,,4,text,3,,".split(',').filter(function(s){return !!s;});` would be cleaner.

Comment: Define **cleaner**. I guess that attach a new function to the prototype is more reusable, better maintenance, adds functionality and simplicity. The code you write needs a long explain to understand at the first view. In my answer, you see `array.clean()`  and you understand ipso facto what function makes.

Answer (score 2):

This, most probably, can't be done using a single replace, as Javascript regex is relatively limited, but you could try:

```
var str = "(,,,text,,4,text,3,,)"
str.replace(/^\(,+/g, "(")
   .replace(/,+\)$/,  ")")
   .replace(/,+/,     ",");
// → "(text,4,text,3)"
```

Note those are 3 separate cases for the beginning, end (eliminate commas), and middle (replace multiple commas with single ones).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 3 replaces:

1. Change all "many commas" to a single comma
2. Remove the first comma after the first parenthesis.
3. Remove the last comma before the last parenthesis.

```js
var str = '(,,,text,,4,text,3,,)';

str = str
  .replace(/,+/g, ',')
  .replace(/^\(,/, '(')
  .replace(/,\)$/, ')');

alert(str);
```